# Extract first Element of List in List

Tags: r

I have a list of lists where I want to extract only the first item and write these values into a vector. 
I have urls which I parse for text and then retrieve the language (package cld2). My problem is that sometimes there are up to 3 values if the language is mixed ("en" "de" for example) so I only want to save the first one.
I know how to do it with a for-loop but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way? Not too knowledgeable about R but I heard you should try to avoid for loops if possible.

```
library(cld2)
library(rvest)
urls_test <- c("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1444419223/safetea-towel-fire-resistant-kitchen-towel", "https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1704155986/des-vacances-en-enfer")
get_lang <- function(x) { read_html(x, trim = TRUE) %>% html_nodes(".js-full-description") %>% html_text() %>% detect_language()}
lang_codes <- map(urls_test, get_lang)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to use `pluck`

```
library(purrr)
map(lang_codes, pluck, 1)
```

---

Or in `base R` with `lapply`

```
sapply(lang_codes, `[[`, 1)
#[1] "en" "fr"
```

Comment: I think your answer is right but I actually don't have a list in a list (I added a screenshot).

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: I edited the code in my post so you can reproduce it

Comment: @beld. I tried your code and it is working fine for me

Comment: @akrun yes it works. I get the list in lang_codes but I think it's a list of character arrays? See my screenshot. Now, I want only the first character.

Comment: @beld. `lapply` returns a `list`, while `sapply` can return a `vector` if lengths are the same.  Please check my update